# How to Send return value to the caller function correctly

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, jquery

Hi i have a code like this.

```
var guiD = myCallerFunction('abc');
alert(guiD);====>Line No Y


function myCallerFunction(name){

 //Some code here

  var terms = termSet.get_terms();
    context.load(terms);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
        while (termEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();
            if (currentTerm.get_name() == termName) {

                alert(currentTerm.get_id()); //====>Line No X
                return currentTerm.get_id();

        }

        }
    }, function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });


}
```

My issue is it gives the value i want at the Line No X. But once i return that value to the caller function, it says value undefined. What would be the reason? It does not give correct value at Line No Y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because of the asynchronous nature of Javascript client object model. The statement after the function does not wait for the function to complete.  In order to avoid this you can use deferreds/promises.

**UPDATE**

Callback Example of your code:

```
myCallerFunction('abc',
    function (terms) {
        var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
        while (termEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();
        if (currentTerm.get_name() == termName) {
            alert(currentTerm.get_id()); //====>Line No X               
        }
    }
},  
function (sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
}); 
function myCallerFunction(name, success, error){
    //Some code here
    var terms = termSet.get_terms();
    context.load(terms);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                success(terms);
            },
            error
        );       
}
```

Comment: Hi @nadeem , do you suggest me to use something like sleep in between 
var guiD = myCallerFunction('abc'); and alert(guiD);====>Line No Y >

Comment: Check this http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/10/sharepoint-using-deferredspromises-or.html

Comment: Hi, I checked that blog. I've already used callbacks here
context.executeQueryAsync
Unfortunately i'm not sure how to use it correctly as you suggested

Comment: I was able to get the proper output by following you, Thank you very much.